# How to Run Java in html?

Tags: java, html

I have this Java Code, want to know how to run it in HTML file as a website: Password Generator by Robotter112:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PasswordGenerator 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int length = 10; // password length
System.out.println(generatePswd(length));
}
static char[] generatePswd(int len)
{
System.out.println("Your Password:");
String charsCaps = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String nums = "0123456789";
String symbols = "!@#$%^&*_=+-/€.?<>)";

String passSymbols = charsCaps + chars + nums + symbols;
Random rnd = new Random();

char[] password = new char[len];
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
{
password[i] = passSymbols.charAt(rnd.nextInt(passSymbols.length()));

}
return password;
}
}
```

So what is the HTML code that can run this java inside the HTML file?

Comment: Use [Java Applets](http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/javaapplets.php)

Comment: java applets or jsp